# Create tar files using nested forloop in R

Tags: r, tar

I have a bunch of files.  They are named as follows:

```
BNT_20170301131740322_123456.csv,  BNT_20170301131740322_7891011.csv
```

In this filename, starting from 5th character to 12th character is the date and 13th and 14th character is the hour.  The rest are dynamically generated and they keep changing.  In the above example the date is 1st March 2017 and the hour is 13.

**Task 1:**
I have to create tar files by zipping all the files that match a specific date and hour.  Thus depending on the date and hour the files gets generated, I will have multiple tar files as output.

**Task 2:**
The next task is to name the tar files in a specific pattern.
Each tar file should be named in the following pattern:

```
BNT_2017030111_2.tar
```

In the above name we can see "BNT_" retained followed by the date and hour and the 2 after the _ (underscore) indicates the number of files inside the tar that matches the date and time. In the above example, the name indicates the files were with the date 1st March 2017 and hour parameter 11 were tarred together and the tar has 2 files inside it.

**What I have done so far:**

```
#set the working directory
setwd("/home/mycomp/Documents/filestotar/")

#list all files
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
```

I have listed the name of all files for reproducibility

```
files <- c("BNT_20170301000000790_123456.csv", "BNT_20170301000000887_7891011.csv",
"BNT_20170301000000947_7430180.csv", "BNT_20170301000001001_2243094.csv", 
"BNT_20170301000001036_14195326.csv", "BNT_20170301000001036_14770776.csv", 
"BNT_20170301000001078_10692013.csv", "BNT_20170301000001089_2966772.csv", 
"BNT_20170301000001100_10890506.csv", "BNT_20170301000001576_7430180.csv")
```

My code:

```
library(stringr)
#extract date and time and set the pattern to identify the files in the folder
#extracts date from the file name
d <- substr(files, 5,12)

#extracts hour from the file name
e <- substr(files, 13,14)

#creates a pattern that can be used to identify the files matching the pattern.
pat <- paste("BNT","_",unique(d),unique(e),sep="")

#creates the count of files with unique hour parameter.  This will be used to create the name for the tar file.
f <- table(paste(d,e,sep=""))

#create unique names for the tar files
g <- unique(paste("BNT",unique(d),unique(e),f,sep="_"))

#pasting the extension .tar to the name of the file
h <- paste(g,".tar",sep="")



#create a nested forloop to tar the files recursively
for (name in h) {
  for (i in seq_along(pat)) {
    filestotar = for (i in seq_along(pat)) {list.files(path = "/home/mycomp/Documents/filestotar/", pattern = pat[i])}
  }
  tar(tarfile = name, files = filestotar)
}
```

The above creates the required number of tar files.   But the tar files includes all the files in the folder in the first tar itself and recursively includes all the newly tar files with the original files in the folder in all the subsequent tar files.

For example, the first tar file has all the csv files instead of only those that matches the pattern `pat`

The second tar file has the first tar file + it has all the csv files instead of only those that matches the pattern `pat`.

Now this continues for every tar file that gets created and the last tar file has all the tar files that got created + all the files that matches `pat`.

**The desired output is:**

Tar only those files that matches the date and hour in the file name and name them with BNT_ + Date + Hour + Number of files + .tar which would look like as follows:

```
BNT_2017030111_2.tar
```

Have created folder with dummy files...just in case if that helps:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwPrNXRo3C1aaUN2WmMtS3dpZ1U
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a loop (not necessary, but my choice here), you could create a data.frame which holds all the information on the files. In turn you can slice and dice it to get the appropriate file names you want.

```
xy <- data.frame(files = files, date = d, hour = e)

out <- split(xy, f = list(xy$date, xy$hour))

result <- sapply(out, FUN = function(x) {
  nfiles <- nrow(x)
  name <- paste("BNT_", unique(x$date), unique(x$hour), "_", nfiles, ".tar", sep = "")

  ### just for show, you can remove ###
  message(sprintf("For %s extracting %s files:", name, nfiles)) 
  for (i in x$files) {
    message(i)
  }
  ### end just for show ###
  tar(tarfile = name, files = x$files)
})
```

Comment: One of my requirements was renaming the filename to include the number of files tar has...and also the strsplit fetches the complete string as opposed to only the first 10 characters from the underscore after BNT.  Since the rest of the characters in my filename keeps changing I tried `strsplit` wrapped with a `substring` and get the first 10 characters...but couldn't loop through the other file names where the 9th and 10th characters (hours) changes...i am sorry if I have missed something from your code...could you please help me understand

Comment: @Apricot my solution only speaks to the last part of your code. `pat` remains the same as you create it (and which probably works). The rest is just how to find similar file names and put them into the same tar. Perhaps you could edit your question and specify which file should be tared where.

Comment: @akrun Would you be able to help me with a solution for this question?

Comment: @Apricot perhaps if you edit your question and specify what goes in, what comes out...

Comment: I have edited and I hope the edits provide a better view of what I was trying to achieve